# Opposite single/double quotes using pymongo command

Tags: python, json, pymongo, quotes

I am trying to take user input, create a URI, and add it with a collection in Pymongo, but whenever I try to do this, the format gets messed up and I cant figure out how to fix it. 
When running the line:

```
print(db.command("create", "storage", someStorage={ "URI": {FS_URI}}))
```

where "Storage" is the collection,
I want the object to be {"fs" : "something://a:b"} or {'fs' : 'something://a:b'}

```
 FS_URI = ('\"fs\" : \"'+URI+'\"')
```

gives the error: Cannot encode object: {'"fs" : "something://a:b"'}

```
FS_URI = ("fs\" : \"%s" % URI)
```

gives the error" Cannot encode object: {'fs" : "something://a:b'}

```
FS_URI = ("fs\' : \'%s" % URI)
```

gives the error" Cannot encode object: {"fs' : 'something://a:b"}

The quotes are always unmatching, or have extra quotes around them. 
I have tried the command with the actual URI in the quote format I want, and it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using a dict solved this problem, by changing

```
FS_URI = ("fs\" : \"%s" % URI)
```

to a JSON object rather than a string:

```
FS_URI = {"fs": "{}".format(URI)}
```

solved this problem